# npm install dosen't install dev dependencies

Tags: npm, package.json, npm-install

I have a project where I use npm for handling dependencies. The project is bundled with Webpack and will run on the client (it's built for using gh-pages for hosting) with no production dependencies. Therefore I have only `devDependencies` in my `package.json`. However, when I run `npm install` nothing gets installed. When I run `npm install --dev` my dependencies gets installed as they are supposed to. Since `--dev` is deprecated I tried with `npm install --only=dev` as well, however nothing gets installed then either! Is there something broken in my `package.json` (inserted below) or am I misunderstanding npm?

```
{
 "name": "Boilerplate",
 "version": "0.0.1",
 "description": "A boilerplate to quickly get started with an offline first React/Redux app",
 "repository": {
   "type": "git",
   "url": "https://github.com/OskarKlintrot/Offline-First-React-And-Redux-Boilerplate"
 },
 "scripts": {
   "start": "webpack-dev-server",
   "build": "webpack --progress --colors --production"
 },
 "private": true,
 "devDependencies": {
   "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
   "babel-eslint": "^4.0.5",
   "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
   "babel-polyfill": "^6.2.0",
   "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
   "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
   "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
   "eslint": "^1.1.0",
   "eslint-loader": "^1.0.0",
   "eslint-plugin-react": "^3.13.1",
   "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
   "history": "^1.17.0",
   "react": "^0.14.2",
   "react-dom": "^0.14.2",
   "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
   "react-mdl": "^1.0.2",
   "react-redux": "^4.0.4",
   "react-router": "^1.0.2",
   "react-tap-event-plugin": "^0.2.1",
   "redux": "^3.0.5",
   "redux-devtools": "^3.0.0",
   "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.0.1",
   "redux-devtools-log-monitor": "^1.0.1",
   "redux-history-transitions": "^1.0.0",
   "redux-thunk": "^1.0.2",
   "transfer-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.4",
   "webpack": "^1.12.9",
   "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
 }
}
```

Comment: Which version of npm are you running? According to the docs (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install), `npm install` by default should install everything. Do you have a `--production` flag set somewhere in your command, or `NODE_ENV=production` in your environment?

Comment: I where using v3.3.12. Just as you said I do remember having `NODE_ENV` set to production (which in Windows is stored as an environment variables permanently). After I posted my question I had updated npm to v3.7.1 and now when I tried it again it worked. Also, after my installation the env variable have disappeared. So it's hard to tell exactly what went wrong but at least now it works! Do you know if the behavior of `npm install` has changed since v3.3.12?